# Real time tick by tick stock quotes using an IP and port

Tags: vb.net, stockquotes

I want to retrieve real time stock market data from a server with an IP address and port.

What information is out there for acquiring this data?

Comment: Take a look into websockets.  Also personally I rate node.js for the server side of things as it's designed for massively live updates.  I found .net a world of pain in comparison when doing anything more advanced than static html pages interfacing with a db.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281263/where-can-i-get-free-real-time-stock-data

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what kind of service is provided on the server which gives you the tick by tick data. It can have an API which you can consume like the one Yahoo has.

You do not need client server programming. From what I know is you can create a web application and use Yahoo! Finance API for getting stock ticker.

Check this for more information
http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_FIN&locale=en_US&id=SLN2340&impressions=true

My Bad : do you have a server where you can get the ticks????

Comment: but yahoo finance and Google finance are not provide tick to tick stock data I think it provide 5 to 6 min delay data.

Comment: suppose i have xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Ip and xxxx port so how can i Retrieve real time Data from it.?? Thanks for your Replay